# Laravel Get item syntax

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I use Laravel with **foreach** in a **blade.php**

```
{{ $users = App\User::where('user_id', $post->user_id)->get() }}
```

and I got the result of this which show on the page

> [{"user_id":"123","email":"123@com","password":"1234","first_name":"Tony"}]

But I want to get **"Tony"** only, how can I call?

Answer (score 1):

```
{{ ($users = App\User::where('user_id', $post->user_id)->first())->first_name }}
```

Or better in sense of performance, if you select posts with user:

```
{{ $post->user->first_name }}
```

But it is better to prepare necessary data in controller.

Answer (score 0):

`get()` returns an array, you should use `first()`

```
{{ ($users = App\User::where('user_id', $post->user_id)->first())->first_name }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you are using foreach in blade. Try something like this

```
@foreach($user as $u)
    {{$u->first_name}}
@endforeach
```

This will give you `first_name` for all users